# Why is create tag synonyms entry missing from reputation faq

Tags: discussion, support

Just noticed that `create tag synonyms` is missing from additional privileges list of [reputation faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation). I was just curious to know if is there a reason?

Comment: Hey, yeah, [there it is on the privileges page](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms). I'd guess it was just an oversight that happened because that privilege was added relatively recently (i.e. after the most recent revision to the site FAQ).

Comment: @PopularDemand I was thinking that this could be one of the causes, thanks.